# Attaching UIButton on top of UIScrollView or UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best approach for attaching a `UIButton` on top of `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` so when the view is scrolled, the button stays in its place.

Here examples below:

`UIButton` stays in the right bottom corner when the view is scrolled.

[google+ app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QArgI.jpg)

[yahoo mail app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Oai1.png)

Comment: My first instinct is to place the button outside of the uiscrollview or uitableview where you would like it and then the scrolling will have no affect on it. This way you can place it over either of those but since its not inside of them it won't scroll with them.

Comment: This made it much clearer to tackle the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.  Lay Out your button in a view that is outside of the tableviewcontroller.  Then drag an outlet to the tableviewcontroller file.  Then add it in code. This code would hold it at the top of the screen.

```
    @IBOutlet var buttonView: UIView!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.view.addSubview(buttonView)
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var rect = self.buttonView.frame
    rect.origin.y = max(0,scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top)
    self.buttonView.frame = rect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for great answers!
I got it worked through storyboard by moving the button from scrollView  to View itself. That way it's attached on UIView and it's independent of scrollview.

[storyboard snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGyuh.png)

So now the structure is:

```
- View
  - ScrollView
  - Button
```

Before it was:

```
- View
  - ScrollView
    - Button
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about doing this but two that I use most often are as follows.

1. One approach is embedding the view controller within a navigation controller. This will set a bar on the top and bottom if you choose that you can place bar button items upon.
2. Another approach is to place a UIView along the top and snap the constraints to the left, right, and top with 0 no-margin. Then set the height. I usually use 40px for the height but you can use what is applicable to your needs. After that you can place a button in that UIView and then set constraints on it to keep in in place.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this isn't reliably possible to do with the scrollView itself.

My solution is usually to put anything that needs to float above the tableView/scrollView in a plain ViewController that also contains the tableView/scrollView parent.

If you're using storyboards with a UITableViewController scene, this will likely mean you need to use another scene with UIViewController with a container that has your UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

For UITableView use tableHeaderView. For UIScrollView you need to create a separate view not in the scroll view's hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to put your `UIButton` in a `UIToolbar`, and then make the toolbar a child of the `UINavigationController`'s view. After that, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, you can set the `rect` of the toolbar to sit just below the navigation bar and offset the top of the `UIScrollView` or `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add button which you want in the storyboard.
2. Design your scrollview
3. self.view.sendSubviewToBack(scrollViewObj)(in the code)

This worked for me.